# Where can I ask a PayPal business question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for a site where I can ask a PayPal business account question. The essence of my question would be:

**Am I obligated to use PayPal's invoicing system for their online payments service?**

And I will go on to explain:

They are US based and most articles on tax are US law based. I'm in the Romania / EU. Romanian law is very picky on how an invoice should look like and is administered. For that I already have a service provider with whom I'm generating invoices manually.

- *[Personal Finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour)*? It's not personal, although I suspect most people there know PayPal and the answer to my question.
- *[Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/tour)*? Too theoretical I think.
- *[Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour)*? Perhaps, because I'm most worried about the legal aspect of a US company generating invoices. (Which I prefer to avoid.)

PayPal's help information all point to "how to do it". But before I start going down this road, I prefer to know where it will end up. And perhaps others here have the experience already.

Comment: This sounds more like a question aimed directly at customer service of PayPal, hence **none** of the SE sites would be a good fit for your question

Comment: That sounds like you're looking for an SE site that does not exist (yet). ie. it's a matter for Area51. I'm wondering myself why there isn't a general business SE site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to ask PayPal yourself, there's little chance random strangers on the Internet know the answer to this question. Yes, as you mentioned, somebody might have had a similar experience before, but chances are slim.

PayPal has a [support site](https://www.paypal.com/pf/smarthelp/home?selectedExp=business) for business accounts, that seems to be the right place. There's a 'Contact us' form if you can't find your answer in the FAQ or the forum. In any case, [Stack Exchange is not customer support for PayPal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/4751173).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. Been going through the PayPal site for hours now, but its not very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

There was a Stack Exchange site in beta that would probably have suited your question. It was closed 5 years ago:

[Startup Business](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business)

It seems the only real option to post this question would be to start a new site on Area 51.

Comment: Actually, there was a second attempt at starting a Startups site, but it too ended up failing. Stack Exchange seems to be closing new proposals to start it up again on sight.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog you mean it's banned or simply fails inevitably?

Comment: No, they're closed on sight, with a notice that "Stack Exchange is no longer interested in having a site in this space".

Comment: is a dupehammer for site proposals as it appears to be discussed here: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12325/dont-allow-votes-as-duplicates-of-closed-proposals-beta-sites

Comment: First, since that question was posted, the ability for normal users to vote to close proposals has been removed, now only Stack Exchange employees can close proposals. Second, they never close proposals as duplicates of closed ones, but instead as "not a viable proposal".